# How to convert Odata request to JSON response

Tags: odata

The response has been returned as Iterable object. I need to return any response as json response.

Example, the below returns a different return type

```
ClientEntitySetIterator<ClientEntitySet, ClientEntity> iterator =
            readEntities(edm, serviceUrl, "employee");
```

Instead of iterator need to return the content as JSON directly or retrieve the response as JSON without having any mapper or custom code.

Please advise.

Comment: You should clarify your question. Also it's also nice to provide [mcve] or any code (even not working) you've created so far

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko i have edited the code and please kindly help me with your comments

Comment: I don't know what you do inside `readEntities` method, but I assume that you build ODataRequest object (like this `odataClient.retrieveRequestFactory.getEntityRequest(uri)`), then you can call `rawExecute` (instead of `execute`) and transform resulting `InputStream` into a String. That would give you the raw JSON